# Created color boxes for a legend in HTML and CSS, but can't get two color boxes on the same line

Tags: html, css

I'm currently in the process of creating a legend for a table that has highlighted rows, but I can't seem to get two color boxes on the same `li`.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="input-color">
            <input type="text" value="Blue/White - Alternating Rows" readonly="true" style="border:0;width:200px"/>
            <div class="color-box" style="background-color: #6DC2FF;"></div>
            <div class="color-box" style="background-color: white;"></div>    
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

With the following CSS...

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;       
   }

.input-color {
    position: relative;
}

.input-color input {
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.input-color .color-box {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Any ideas? Assuming I know how to use JSFiddle, here it is:

https://jsfiddle.net/1ywpxxks/1/

Comment: You are positioning _all_ items absolutely at the very same position …

Comment: exactly as what @CBroe mentioned, you need to adjust margin for second `<div>` for different positioning, adding a `margin-top` to the second `<div>` will solve your issue

Comment: Ahh, crap. I see what's going on now. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `float: left;` to prevent `div` from breaking lines. You can also set `disply: inline-block;`.